# Formula for Alternating Geometric Series

Tags: calculus

I am aware of the following formula:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^n=\frac{1}{1+r}$$

However, I am having difficulty understanding if there is a simple formula for the following equation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^{2n}={ }?$$

In addition, what about the following?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}r^{2n+1}={ }?$$

I'm not sure how to go about identifying how to modify the original formula to fit the previous two, if that is even possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the formula $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ to expand $(x^2+1)^2$?  If so, a similar operation on your first sum will give the second.

Comment: It may be best to think of $1+t+t^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-t}$ (when $|t|\lt 1$) as the basic formula, and *use* it to find all other related "sums."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-r)^n=\cfrac{1}{1-(-r)}=\cfrac{1}{1+r}$$
So you can do the same for two following series :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-r^2)}^n $$$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}r^{2n+1}=-r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nr^{2n}$$

Comment: @TylerMurry, in that case, the fact that the serie is an alternate one doesn't really matter since you can recognize a geometric serie (I assumed $|r|<1$). Moreover, $-r^2$ is negative.